# Changing button content with code behind

Tags: wpf, button

This is my code:

```
Button obj = sender as Button;
        obj.Content = "fgfgfgfghhhhhhhhhhhhhpetko";
        obj.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        obj.Height = 20;
```

It's in the MouseEntered event. When I get with the mouse over the button, the button changes its height, but it doesn't change its Content. The text remains the same. Why is this happening?

Here's the button style:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                        <Border.Background>
                            SlateBlue
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/test.png"></Image>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <TextBlock.Name>
                                        petko
                                    </TextBlock.Name>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's how I use it:

```
<Button  MouseEnter="MouseEntered" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Name="btnHelp" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="ViewModel/MyPage.xaml" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=frmContent}" ></Button>
```

Comment: It working fine for me. Button content got update, could you please actual code what you are doing

Comment: Are You sure You added event handler to the button? I see no handler specification in your xaml

Comment: @Teaman Yes I'm sure. I updated the question again.

Comment: @petko_stankoski do you want to change `TextBlock` text or replace whole `Content` (including the `Image`)?

Comment: yes, You have a too complicated code, try to explain us what do You want to happen on MouseEnter.

Comment: @dkozi I want to change the TextBlock text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used Your template, setting any content for the button did not work for me (even if hardcoded in the XAML file). I've modified Your template a little bit not to overwrite `ContentContainer.Content` inside the `ControlTemplate` and it seems to work correctly now and is updated on mouse enter event.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                            <Border.Background>
                                SlateBlue
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Resources/test.png"></Image>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Please let me know if this solves Your issue.

Comment: Pls see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532028/change-content-of-image-and-of-textblock-when-the-image-and-the-textblock-are-in

Answer (score 1):

You have hard coded the template, you have to use template binding to update this.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                        <Border.Background>
                            SlateBlue
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/test.png"></Image>
                                     <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                               </StackPanel>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Pls see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532028/change-content-of-image-and-of-textblock-when-the-image-and-the-textblock-are-in

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `ContentPresenter.Content` inside the template. This property is bound to the actual content of the button. You are supposed to set this content for the button iself, not the template.