# Setting text property to a button doesn't work

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls

This is my UserControl file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProject.ButtonWithImage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:myProject="clr-namespace:myProject;assembly=myProject.BusinessLogic"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="ImagedControl"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Button Height="35" Width="90" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"
        Click="OnClick" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 1 1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImagedButton, Path=ImageSource}" Stretch="None" Margin="0 0 5 0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ImagedButton, Path=Text}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                <Border.Background>
                    SlateBlue
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And in a page I set up a button like this:

```
<myProject:ButtonWithImage ImageSource="/Resources/test.png" Text="Back" Name="btnBack1" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="ViewModel/Categories.xaml" />
```

However the text and the imagesource aren't on the button! They don't appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change Name="btnBack1" to x:Name="btnBack1" it maybe not the case, but it is safer

Comment: and add  Name="ImagedButton" to your UserControl

Comment: *change Name="btnBack1" to x:Name="btnBack1" it maybe not the case, but it is safer*... what makes you think that doing that is *safer*?

Comment: at least in VS2010, VS2012, VS2013 while using .Net 3.5 You may face a situation, when an UserControl with Name property specified will cause VS to generate xaml validity issue with an odd description in output window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Created Button Usercontrol**

```
<Button x:Class="WpfApplication5.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Content="ok" Foreground="White" Height="30" Width="90" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 1 1">   
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
            <Border.Background>
                SlateBlue
            </Border.Background>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 0 0 0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

---

**c# code**

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : Button
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**xaml window**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:myProject="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<myProject:UserControl1  Content="Button Text" Tag="btn2.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have named your `UserControl` `ImageControl`, but then you have tried to access it in your XAML using the name `ImageButton`. You'll have more luck if you stick with the one name. Try this instead:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProject.ButtonWithImage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:myProject="clr-namespace:myProject;assembly=myProject.BusinessLogic"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="ImagedControl"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Button Height="35" Width="90" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"
        Click="OnClick" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 1 1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImagedControl, Path=ImageSource}" Stretch="None" Margin="0 0 5 0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ImagedControl, Path=Text}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                <Border.Background>
                    SlateBlue
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

This also assumes that you have correctly declared two `DependencyProperty`s of the correct type, named `ImagesSource` and `Text` in your `UserControl` and have set appropriate values for them.