# Add second image to content of button

Tags: wpf, button, datatemplate

This is the peace of code for the button:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
            <Border.Background>
                SlateBlue
            </Border.Background>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 0 0 0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,10,0" />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

As you can see, my button has an image and a text. However, I want to add another image after the text. How do I do this? I already use the Tag property once.

Here's how I use the button:

```
<myProject:ButtonWithTwoImages x:Name="btnHome" Tag="/Resources/Home.png" Content="Home" Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToCategoriesCommand}" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
```

How do I add another image to the button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532028/change-content-of-image-and-of-textblock-when-the-image-and-the-textblock-are-in using resource or using dependency property.

Comment: what is ButtonWithTwoImages? is it a user control?

Comment: @YuliamChandra ButtonWithTwoImages is the name of the file which defines the button. That file has root element Button, and in it is the code <Button.Template> from the above code.

Comment: @petko_stankoski, you can use dependency property

Answer (score 1):

I created a new user control called ButtonWithTwoImages, here is the code.

## Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserControl.ButtonWithTwoImages"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
        <Border.Background>
            SlateBlue
        </Border.Background>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 0 0 0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,10,0" />
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 0 0 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

## Xaml.cs

```
public partial class ButtonWithTwoImages : UserControl
{
    public ButtonWithTwoImages()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource Image1
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(Image1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Image1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Image1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Image1", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonWithTwoImages), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ImageSource Image2
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(Image2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Image2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Image2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Image2", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonWithTwoImages), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

## How To Use It

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mylib="clr-namespace:WpfUserControl">
    <Grid>
        <mylib:ButtonWithTwoImages Image1="Images\A.jpg" Image2="Images\B.jpg"></mylib:ButtonWithTwoImages>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```