# Horizontal alignment in a button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

Here's my code for the button:

```
<Button //namespaces
        x:Class="myProject.MyButton"
        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
        Foreground="White"
        Height="60"
        Width="200"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Padding="0 0 1 1"
        >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8">
                <Border.Background>
                    #006BB7
                </Border.Background>
                <DockPanel Margin="3">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Height="30" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 0 0 0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Bmp}" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 10 0"></Image>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

When I call it like this:

```
<ui:MyButton x:Name="btnGo" Tag="/Resources/Go.png" Content="Go" Command="{Binding Path=GoCommand}" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
```

and everything looks like I want it to look: the first image isn't shown, and the third part of the button (the second image) is aligned right.

However, here:

```
<ui:MyButton Margin="10" Content="{Binding MyName}" Tag="{Binding Path}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Resources>
         <BitmapImage x:Key="Bmp" UriSource="/Images/arrowRight.png"></BitmapImage>
    </Button.Resources>
 </ui:MyButton>
```

Whn I call the button like this, the text and the second image aren't shown. All that is shown is the first image and it is stretched via the whole button's width. Why is this happening? I want to make this to behave as the other one.

Comment: If you're going to define a `MyButton` custom class for your `Button`, then just add proper `DependencyProperty`s to it to bind to your two `ImageSource` properties.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm not defining a class for the button.

Comment: Then what is this: `<Button x:Class="myProject.MyButton" ...`?

Comment: @Sheridan There is a class, but that's the one which extends the Button class. There's nothing else. There are no defines properties.

Comment: OMG! *If you're going to define a `MyButton` custom class for your `Button`* (which you have done), *then just add proper `DependencyProperty`s to it to bind to your two `ImageSource` properties.* That's the solution... just add `DependencyProperty`s to your extended class and bind to them.

Comment: @Sheridan LOL... I didn't create a class! I just created a class, but it derives from `Button`, it doesn't have any properties!! You have to admit this is hilarious...

Comment: @petko_stankoski I suggest you read [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN before trying to create custom controls.

Comment: @HeenaPatil Your link doesn't work, pls fix it.

Comment: @petko_stankoski its working here..i tested...you run code separately and try it.plz tell me if there is any error

Comment: @HeenaPatil No, I didn't remove the question.

Comment: @petko_stankoski i am sorry.it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In [Change content of Image and of TextBlock when the Image and the TextBlock are in a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532028/change-content-of-image-and-of-textblock-when-the-image-and-the-textblock-are-in) we are using resource for button and here we are using for `<ui:MyButton>`

```
<ui:MyButton Margin="10" Content="{Binding MyName}" Tag="{Binding Path}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ui:MyButton.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Bmp" UriSource="/Images/arrowRight.png"></BitmapImage>
    </ui:MyButton.Resources>
</ui:MyButton>
```

Comment: Its working here.i checked here using your code only.check your image source.

Comment: @petko_stankoski please be specific when communicating your problems here in StackOverflow. *"it doesn't work"* is completely vague, unspecific and doesn't help people understand your problem. Please explain your current situation with the highest possible level of detail and also please explain what is your expected result.

Comment: @HighCore I'm sorry. I doesn't work - The problem remains the same as before. Only the first image is shown and it's stretched.